# Inserting html content into another div using the href of a link to insert certain html of a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Trying to insert the a certain div once a link is clicked. This link has the div `id` on its `href`. So I would like to fetch this data and use it to insert the html into a certain placement in my html DOM.

HTML:

```
<a class="hotspot article-1-slide-1" href="#product-1">
    <span class="hotspot-label pp-icon icon-anime-left-arrow">article 1</span>
</a>
```

I would like to insert it into this space:

```
<article class="product-hotspot-display">
    <a class="product-hotspot-close pp-icon icon-cross js-product-hotspot-close"></a>

    // HERE

</article>
```

I think that .html() would be the answer. Using this code I get an error. What am I doing wrong?

```
//product link
    $(document).on('click', '.hotspot', function (event) {
     event.preventDefault();
     var productId = $(this).attr('href');
     var productHtml = $(productId).html();
     productHtml.insertAfter('.js-product-hotspot-close');
     panel.addClass('is-open');
     //console.log(productHtml);
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
$(document).on('click','.hotspot' , function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).insertAfter('.js-product-hotspot-close');
});
```

Comment: If I check console I get: Object #product-1 has no method 'insertAfter'

Comment: It must work, here is a link to working example : [jsFiddle - click here](http://jsfiddle.net/79JSH/)

Answer (score 0):

This worked out for me:

```
var panel = $('.product-hotspot-display');
var slideWrapper = $('.slide-wrapper');

//product link
$(document).on('click','.hotspot' , function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var productId = $(this).attr('href');
    var productHtml = $(productId).html();
    var contentHook = $('.js-product-hotspot-data');

    contentHook.empty();
    contentHook.html(productHtml);
    panel.addClass('is-open');

});
```

I hope it helps anybody else!